# Eliminar datos específicos en Firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase

Lo que quiero hacer es un sistema de comentarios a cada publicación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public void remove(NewsModel news){
    reference.child(news.getKey()).removeValue(); // esto si lo hace
    comments.child("news").orderByChild("id").equalTo(news.getKey()).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            dataSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Así es como elimino cada publicación. Me funciona cuando esa publicación tiene un solo comentario, sin embargo se me cierra la app cuando intento eliminar una publicación con 2 o más comentario.

Todo eso lo hago desde mi adaptador de mi recyclerview y así mando a llamar a ese método:

```
holder.delete.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            remove(newsList.get(position));
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: podrías agregar como haces tu referencia? mas que nada por que es importante ver a que ruta apuntas cuando haces esto

reference.child(news.getKey()).removeValue(); // esto si lo hace

Answer (score 1):

Hola yo lo eh hecho asi espero que les ayude

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("peticiones");
            DatabaseReference currentUserBD = mDatabase.child(id);
            currentUserBD.removeValue();
```